# Does Resharper support tests written in Typescript?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, typescript, jasmine

I have a unit test written in Typescript (using Jasmine):

```
describe("test fixture", () => {
   it("should pass", () => {
      var x = 1;
      expect(x).not.toBeNull();
   });
});
```

I can see that Resharper (8.*) adds the icon to run such test, but after running it tells me that "Test wasn't run"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that at this stage Reaharper v8 only has the basic usage. They planning to add more typescript features in 8.1 onwards. 8.1 is currently EAP.
You can find more information below.

> We have just recently announced TypeScript support as part of
>   ReSharper 8.1 EAP, and this blog post is intended to give you more
>   details on this exciting development. Note that ReSharper 8.1 is only
>   the first milestone in supporting TypeScript, and while we’re ready to
>   show a first set of TypeScript features,
>
> there’s still quite a long journey ahead.

So the unit testing features with typescript does not seems to have supported yet.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/10/typescript-support-resharper-81/

Comment: From jetbrains issue tracker: typescript support for unit testing will  be added in version 9.0

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-394249